# Filtering nested array of struct in swift 5

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, closures

```
struct Objects {
        var sectionName : String!
        var sectionObjects : [CountryList]!
    }

var objectArray = [Objects]()
```

Here `objectArray` is my `tableView` data source where `sectionObjects` is an array of `CountryList` `struct`.

```
struct CountryList: Codable {
    let country_id: String?
    let country_name: String?
    let country_code:  String?
    let country_flag_url: String?

    init(countryID: String, countryName: String, countryCode:  String, countryFlagURL: String) {
        self.country_id = countryID
        self.country_name = countryName
        self.country_code = countryCode
        self.country_flag_url = countryFlagURL
    }
}
```

I want to filter my `objectArray` according to `country_name`.

This is what I have done in `UISearchResultsUpdating`.

```
extension CountryListViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {
    public func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        guard let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text else {return}
        if searchText == "" {
            objectArray += objectArray
        } else {
            objectArray += objectArray

            objectArray = objectArray.filter {
                let countryListArray = $0.sectionObjects!
                for countryList in countryListArray {
                    print("cName \(String(describing: countryList.country_name))")
                    countryList.country_name!.contains(searchText)
                }
            }
        }
        self.countryListTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

And getting two errors:

> Result of call to 'contains' is unused
>
> Missing return in a closure expected to return 'Bool'

What am I missing here? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your contains is buried in a for loop.

Comment: given your `init` don't make a variable optional `String?` if it won't be , so remove the `init` method and all of the `?` trailings then you'll get an automatic init for the struct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` expects a bool return inside it so You need

```
var objectArray = [Objects]()
var filtered = [Objects]()

filtered = objectArray.filter {
  let countryListArray = $0.sectionObjects
  for countryList in countryListArray {
    print("cName \(String(describing: countryList.country_name))")
       if countryList.country_name!.contains(searchText) {
             return true 
        } 
   }
   return false
}
```

**Or** better

```
filtered = objectArray.filter { $0.sectionObjects.filter { $0.country_name!.contains(searchText) }.count != 0 }
```

**Tip :** use another array `filtered` to hold filtered data as not to overwrite main content in `objectArray`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. I am struggling to accommodate it within the same array. Let me try with a different `filterArray`.

Comment: you need `var isSearching = true/false` to register the current state and so on to correctly configure the tableView delegate and datasource to return/use the relevant array

Comment: Well, I think I don't need the `var sectionName : String!` out of my `objectArray.filter`. Is it possible to get the only `var sectionObjects : [CountryList]!` list? Because I don't have to maintain any `section header`. Life will be easier. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: Thank you. Every answer I saw only returned the inner object. This is the best solution.